# Scraping Statefarm with Selenium results in 404 after button click

Tags: python, selenium

I have [the following script](https://gist.github.com/8W9aG/448e588177ff5d554291c57ba7c86fce) in python where I try and go through the [Statefarm insurance quote form](https://www.statefarm.com/) automatically. However upon pressing continue I am redirected to a page which produces a 404. If I run the selenium browser and perform the action of clicking the button myself it does keep going. I am wondering how they are achieving this detection, and what I should do to get around it.

Comment: so basically with Selenium, it gets auto detected ?

Comment: My script gets auto-detected, but not just the act of using selenium. I have tried entering keys in with delays and clicking on positions rather than elements but to no avail.